# Fully closing application in C# just won't work

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm writing a simple game and I have a function that basically should just exit the application or rather close everything currently open in C# (I'm using Windows Forms).

```
private void ExitApp()
{
    Application.Exit();
}
```

However, nothing will work. I have tried using `Environment.Exit(0)`, `Application.Exit`, tried using a for loop to close every form but it just won't work. What I have noticed is that even if I press the X button, the solution won't close, but something seems to be running in the background and I do not know what. Browsed Stackoverflow forum for similar issues, browsed other forums, googled for days, but nothing seemed to help.

This is the code for opening more forms :

```
Podešavanja p = new Podešavanja();

private void Settings_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
        this.Close();
        Menu m = new Menu();
        m.Show();
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        this.Close();
        Menu m = new Menu();
        m.Show();
}
```

The `SettingsFormClosing` event actually just opens up a new Form for me, without closing the previous one, why, I do not know.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please post you `Main` method to see if something weird happens there.

Comment: If you use threads inside your app, set IsBackground property for threads to true. This will allow c# to auto close your threads when app exist. But please keep in mind that it is better to control your threads in a better way.

Comment: "won't work" is not a good problem description. Why do you think the program is still running? Is the window left open? Can you see the process in task manager still?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that your forms are all running on the same thread. Take a look at your Program.cs file. See how it calls Application.Run(New Form1())? This is where your application form initially runs on the application thread.

So the problem we have here is: you are trying to close your Form, which is hosting your second form. Suppose your a single form with a button control on it. Now suppose you tried to tell your application you wanted the window form to close, but wanted the button to stay active and open -- crazy right? Well what you are trying to do is essentially the same thing -- mind you I am basing this on the assumption you are not multithreading. Your Form1 is hosting your Form2 instance, and thus you cannot run Form2 if Form1 is disposed. The best way I can think of, at least off the top of my head, is you need to create a recursive call in your Program.cs and tell it whether or not it needs to run a new Form before it truly exits. This is questionable at best, but it might suffice.

So let's modify our Program.cs Then:

```
static class Program
{
    //This is where we set the current form running -- or to be run.
    static Form CurrentForm;

    /// <summary>
    /// The main entry point for the application.
    /// </summary>
    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        //Obviously, Form 1 starts everything so we hardcode that here on startup.
        CurrentForm = new Form1();
        //Then call our Run method we created, which starts the cycle.
        Run();
    }

    //This runs the current form
    static void Run()
    {
        //Tell our program to run this current form on the application thread
        Application.Run(CurrentForm);
        //Once the form OFFICIALLY closes it will execute the code below
        //Until that point, imagine Application.Run being stuck there
        if(CurrentForm != null && CurrentForm.IsDisposed == false)
        {
            //If our current form is NOT null and it is NOT disposed,
            //Then that means the application has a new form to display
            //So we will recall this method.
            Run();
        }
    }

    //This method is what we will call inside our forms when we want to
    //close the window and open a new one.
    public static void StartNew(Form form)
    {
        //Close the current form running
        CurrentForm.Close();
        //Set the new form to be run
        CurrentForm = form;

        //Once all this is called, imagine the program now 
        //Releasing Application.Run and executing the code after
    }
}
```

Okay so if you wrap your head around this, then closing and opening a new form is a piece of cake. We simply can open new forms on button click events.

Inside Form1.cs:

```
    private void OpenForm2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Program.StartNew(new Form2());
    }
```

Inside Form2.cs

```
    private void OpenForm1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Program.StartNew(new Form1());
    }
```

I will reiterate, this method is super questionable.... But it may suffice for what ever you are doing. It is also super reusable through your application regardless of the class or form.